# PHP calculation with values from html form won't work

Tags: php, html, forms, calculation

I try to calculate the body mass index from values entered in a HTML form, but I don't get any result.

I'm new to php and I tried it for 30 minutes, without any result. Could you help me, please?

```
<?php
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    ?>  

    <form method="post">

        <p>Größe in Zentimeter:
        <input type="number" name="size">
        </p>

        <p>Gewicht in Kilogramm:
        <input type="numer" name="weight">
        </p>

        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Berechnen"
        </p>

    </form>

    <?php
    $bmi = weight / (size * size);
    echo $bmi;
    ?>
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the dollar in the beginning of some variables. Also, is important to only do the calculation if the user posts the form:

```
    <form method="post">

        <p>Größe in Zentimeter:
        <input type="number" name="size">
        </p>

        <p>Gewicht in Kilogramm:
        <input type="number" name="weight">
        </p>

        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Berechnen"
        </p>

    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['size'])){
      $size = $_POST['size'];
      $weight = $_POST['weight']; 
      $bmi = $weight / ($size * $size);
      echo $bmi;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: also  <input type="numer" name="weight"> should be
 <input type="number" name="weight">

Comment: Oh, wow, I'm stupid D: Thank you!